# Ofbiz multi-tenancy configuration

Tags: multi-tenant, ofbiz

I have installed ofbiz trunk as of today (14-Mar-2024) and configured it to work on multi-tenancy with postgres using following link.

https://medium.com/@mallah.rajesh/single-and-multi-tenant-setup-of-ofbiz-erp-on-ubuntu-linux-an-walkthrough-for-newbies-d61d3552ad62

I have got no error during configuration but its not working. Issue is:

1. Start ofbiz  - works
2. Signin for any one tenant says tenantId=tenant001 - Works and it asks for change of password on first sign-in.
3. Logout
4. Singin using second tenant tenantId=tenant002 - **Does not work**. Incorrect password.
5. Stop ofbiz
6. Start ofbiz - works
7. Singin using second tenant tenantId=tenant002 - **Works**
8. Logout
9. Signin using tenant one tenantId=tenant001 - **Does not work** Incorrect password.

It seems once you sign-in using any tenant it does not switch to second tenant until restart it done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0vUI.png)

Somehow third option where tenant is selected goes missing on this error page.

Of course **Multitenant=Y** is set.

Needs missing configuration / code / db script.